# How to emit an event from grandchildren to grandparent in modern angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

If I have multiple levels of angular components, how can I use `@Output` to emit an event from child to the grand parent?

Grandparent:

```
<parent (handleClick)="grandmaHandleClick($event)">
<parent>
...
grandmaHandleClick(event) {
  console.log('grandma knows you clicked')
}
```

Parent:

```
<child (handleClick)="handleClick($event)">
</child>
```

Child:

```
<div (click)="onClick()">Click button
</div>
...
@Output() handleClick = new EventEmitter
onClick() {
  this.handleClick.emit('clicked a button')
}
```

I am trying to have it so that @Output can prop drill a few components deep, whats the best way to accomplish this, and can you provide example?

Comment: Just use a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) and Subject/BehaviorSubject instead. https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There could be 2 ways:

1. Using `@output`:

**Grandparent**

```
<parent (notifyGrandParent)="grandmaHandleClick($event)">
<parent>
...
grandmaHandleClick(event) {
  console.log('grandma knows you clicked')
}
```

**Parent**:

```
<child (handleClick)="childEvent($event)">
</child>

@Output() notifyGrandParent= new EventEmitter();
childEvent(event) {
  this.notifyGrandParent.emit('event')
}
```

**Child** is implemented properly in the code so it is good to go.

2. Using `BehaviorSubject` via `Service`: With this much level of nesting,  you can actually create some service like `EventService`, and then create `BehaviorSubject` which can directly be subscribed by the GrandParent. Also, to make this `service` more component specific, you can keep this service in a `module` which will have other 3 components (GrandParent, Parent and Child)

```
export class EventService{

 private childClickedEvent = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  emitChildEvent(msg: string){
     this.childClickedEvent.next(msg)
  }

  childEventListner(){
     return this.childClickedEvent.asObservable();
   } 

}
```

and then in `components`:

**ChildComponent**

```
export class ChildComponent{
   constructor(private evtSvc: EventService){}

   onClick(){
     this.evtSvc.emitChildEvent('clicked a button')
   }
}
```

**GrandParent**

```
export class GrandComponent{
   constructor(private evtSvc: EventService){}

   ngOnInit(){
     this.evtSvc.childEventListner().subscribe(info =>{
         console.log(info); // here you get the message from Child component
      })
   }
}
```

Please note that, with `@output` event, you create a tight coupling of components and so a strong dependency (**parent-child-grandchild**) is created. If the component is not reusable and is only created to serve this purpose, then `@output` will also make sense because it'll convey the message to any new developer that they have parent-child relationship.

Creating a service to pass data also exposes the data to other components which can inject `service` in `constructor`.

So, **the decision should be taken accordingly**.

Comment: In the first approach, wouldn' @output be on the child component?

Comment: @user2167582: It has already been handled by you properly using `@Output() handleClick` in `child component` that is why I didnt mention it. Let me add that as well

Comment: Thank you, I did and it works. upon asking this I was also curious if there's a way to pass (boundedEvent) down components without necessarily having to add handler methods to emit back up the hierarchy, seems like it is needed.

Comment: @user2167582: If its just one level of `parent` `child` components, you can use `@Input` and use `ngOnChange` in child to monitor the change in value which is passed to `child component`. Else, if its is multi level component structure, you can again use `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: This was so helpful to me. Just a tiny detail.... In the original post there's the line... `<div (click)="onClick">Click button</div>`. The `onClick` should be `onClick()`. The answer says, "Child is implemented properly in the code so it is good to go" -- so someone might end up confused.

Comment: @DavidSilva: You are correct, my friend!  I'll correct that in the question. Many Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use rxjs/subject, it can be observer and observable in the same time.

Usage:

1. Create Subject property in service:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class AuthService {
  loginAccures: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

2. When event happens in child page/component use:

```
logout() {
  this.authService.loginAccures.next(false);
}
```

3. And subscribe to subject in parent page/component:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  this.authService.loginAccures.subscribe((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
    this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
  })
}
```