# Event emitter not working after using subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dialog which has a button on click of which I have to send data to parent, and from there to parent's parent. I'm getting data in parent, but I'm unable to pass it to the top level component.

my dialog component ts:

```
onClickOfButton(){
    this.buttonClicked.emit(this.data)
    }
```

my parent component ts:

```
@Output() dataPreviewReceived = new EventEmitter<any>();
    
this.dialogRef = this.openDialog(dataOptions);

this.dialogRef.componentInstance.buttonClicked.subscribe((value)=>{
            this.dataPreviewReceived.emit(value)
        })
```

my top level component html:

```
<app-parent (dataPreviewReceived)="onDataReception($event)">
    </app-parent>
```

my top level component ts:

```
onDataReception(data){
    console.log("received data",data)
}
```

But I'm not able to send to top level from inside .subscribe  function. If I use the same emitter outside through some other function, it gets emitted. What am I doing wrong? Is this the right way to do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to emit an event from grandchildren to grandparent in modern angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609069/how-to-emit-an-event-from-grandchildren-to-grandparent-in-modern-angular)

Comment: write console.log in onClickOfButton() check if its working ? 
write console.log  in buttonClicked.subscribe check if its working ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Hi, unfortunately no, it doesn't. Normal event  emitters are working fine but it's not emitting inside `this.dialogRef.componentInstance.buttonClicked.subscribe((value)=>{this.dataPreviewReceived.emit(value) })` . Outside of it the same emitter works fine. I'm not even using an external api or something, so I don't it's an issue of synchronization.

Comment: One small unrelated tip. Try avoid using phrases like parent's parent. It might make sense in your dev environment. But when it's looked at out of context, it creates unnecessary confusion. Try to restrict to one parent, it's child, it's sub-child and so on.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer for your problem? It will be easier to spot the problem there - you may even find it yourself by creating one.

Comment: @hanan Hi, yes, I'm getting data from dialog  and I can console it in my parent. I but can't emit this to grandparent (inside subscription of dialog event). Otherwise emitter is working in a other functions or events .

Comment: @nyxtron This will help you understand the scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609069/how-to-emit-an-event-from-grandchildren-to-grandparent-in-modern-angular

Comment: Create an example on stackblatz ...

Comment: @MikeS.@hanan Hi thanks for the suggestion. I created a stackblitz and it's working fine there. So the problem is obviously my original local code. Anyway, thank you!